# Examples for embedding matplotlib graphs in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to embed a matplotlib graph in tkinter. All the resources I have come across like [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) one or [this one](https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/) make use of the `FigureCanvasTk.show` function and the `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg` class which have been deprecated.

What do I need to use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most up to date examples are to be found in the matplotlib devdocs, http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/.

[This is the devdoc example](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html)  for TK.

To answer the real question in between the lines,

- `FigureCanvasTk.show()` needs to be replaced by `FigureCanvasTk.draw()`
- `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg` needs to be replaced by `NavigationToolbar2Tk`